# Xamarin: app requires camera and access to photos/files - unsure why

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've deployed a Xamarin.Android application to the Google Play store and I've noticed that the Android application needs permission to access the camera as well as photos/files. I'm not sure why because the app has absolutely no functionality that involves the camera or the user's photos/files.

My application uses push notifications and geolocation, and those permissions are requested at app runtime. I was required to add the camera permissions in the AndroidManifest.

Is there some way to find out what SDK or NuGet package is requiring camera permissions? Also, the iOS version doesn't request the camera or photos/files so it seems like its just an Android thing.

Please and thank you!

Comment: Remove the manual manifest permission entry and debug the app, *assuming* you will hit a runtime permission's exception/fault and either from the exception/stacktrace or the device's crash (via logcat) you will be able to determine the cause via the thread call stack.

Comment: So I removed the permissions from the manifest and AssemblyInfo and then re-uploaded to the Google Play store but the Play Store description and app description still mentions needing the Camera. The app doesn't throw any exceptions or crash at all

Comment: What does the final manifest contain? i.e. your release build `obj`'s dir: `obj/Release/android/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml` or unzip the APK and extract the manifest, does still it contain a camera perm?

Comment: Yes actually it includes several permissions that I didn't put there, like android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, etc. What does this mean?

Comment: Go through the 3rd-party packages that you added, string search the `.dll`s if you have to, "something" is adding it...

Comment: You're right, it looks like ZXing, the library used for barcode generation, forces these permissions into the app even though we don't use the ZXing features that make use of the camera (e.g. barcode scanning). This is really unfortunate. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are other ways to generate barcodes, I prefer the "native" methods (easy to wrap via Forms' DependencyInjection), iOS contains CoreImage methods for barcodes and Google has ML Kit/Mobile Vision APIs.... faster, smaller app size, and no extra permissions ;-)

Comment: Thank you I'll look into it !

Comment: FYI for Android it looks like Mobile Vision APIs can only be used for reading barcodes, not for generating them. However apparently if you use the package `ZXing.Net` instead of `ZXing.Net.Mobile` you can accomplish the same barcode generation on Android without the camera permissions being forced on you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ZXing, the library we use for barcode generation, forces these permissions into the app even though we don't use the ZXing features that make use of the camera (e.g. barcode scanning). This is really unfortunate.

There is currently an open issue on the ZXing.Net.Mobile Github to remedy this:
https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/517

**EDIT** it looks like if you use the package `ZXing.Net` instead of `ZXing.Net.Mobile` you can accomplish the same barcode generation on Android without being forced to have camera permissions added in your AndroidManifest.xml.